# How to set Windows not to prompt for password on resume from sleep

Tags: windows, passwords, sleep

My friend wants to make it so he only has to input his password on his laptop when he turns on the computer and logs into it. He wants to make it so if he closes his computer and it goes into sleep or standby, when he wants to use it again he doesn't have to input his password. I was under the impression you couldn't do this but just to make sure if anyone has an answer.....

Comment: What version of windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the power options and disable the prompt to enter password from sleep.